# how to show $\frac{\partial\hat\sigma}{\partial\hat u}\times\frac{\partial\hat\sigma}{\partial\hat v}$ (cross product)

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, differential-geometry

how to show $$\frac{\mathcal{\partial\hat\sigma}}{\partial\hat u}\times\frac{\mathcal{\partial\hat\sigma}}{\partial\hat v}=\left(\frac{\mathcal{\partial u}}{\partial\hat u} \frac{\mathcal{\partial v}}{\partial\hat v} - \frac{\mathcal{\partial u}}{\partial\hat v} \frac{\mathcal{\partial v}}{\partial \hat u}\right)\frac{\mathcal{\partial \sigma}}{\partial u}\times \frac{\mathcal{\partial\sigma}}{\partial v} $$

$\times$: cross product

$\partial$:partial derivative

$$\frac{\mathcal{\partial\hat\sigma}}{\partial\hat u}=\frac{\mathcal{\partial\sigma}}{\partial u}\frac{\mathcal{\partial u}}{\partial\hat u} + \frac{\mathcal{\partial\sigma}}{\partial v}\frac{\mathcal{\partial v}}{\partial\hat u}$$

$$\frac{\mathcal{\partial\hat\sigma}}{\partial\hat v}=\frac{\mathcal{\partial\sigma}}{\partial u}\frac{\mathcal{\partial u}}{\partial\hat v} + \frac{\mathcal{\partial\sigma}}{\partial v}\frac{\mathcal{\partial v}}{\partial\hat v}$$

I have tried a lot, long to write here.
$\hat u$,$\hat v$, $\hat\sigma$,$\sigma$

Comment: I think you could prove this quite quickly using tensors.

Comment: corrected,editted it

Comment: Make sure that you know that $a\times a=0$ and $a\times b=-b\times a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial\hat\sigma}{\partial\hat u}\times\frac{\partial\hat\sigma}{\partial\hat v}
&=&\left(\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat u} + \frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat u}\right)\times\left(\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat v} + \frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat v}\right)\\
&=&\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat u}\times\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat v}+\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat u}\times\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat v}+\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat u}\times\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat v}+\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat u}\times\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat v}\\
&=&\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat u}\times\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat v}-\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u}\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat v}\times\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat u}\\
&=&\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat u}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat v}\cdot\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat u}\cdot\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}\\
&=&\left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat u}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat v}-\frac{\partial u}{\partial\hat v}\frac{\partial v}{\partial\hat u}\right)\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial u}\times\frac{\partial\sigma}{\partial v}.
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 1):

By the chain rule you have $\frac{\partial \hat\sigma}{\partial u}=\frac{\partial \hat\sigma}{\partial \hat u}\frac{\partial \hat u}{\partial u}+\frac{\partial \hat\sigma}{\partial \hat v}\frac{\partial \hat v}{\partial u}$ etc. so the real problem is, given two vectors $a,b$ and linear combinations $\alpha_1 a+\beta_1 b$ and $\alpha_2 a+\beta_2 b$ to compute the cross product

$$(\alpha_1 a+\beta_1 b)\times (\alpha_2 a+\beta_2 b),$$

which is a rather short calculation requiring linear expansion, and application of basic rules of the cross product.